# Case-insensitive queries with Amazon Dynamo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, amazon-dynamodb

In In DynamoDB, string values are case sensitive. In my app, users can search the db for a profile name. However, if they searched for, say 'alan', then 'Alan' would not be returned in the search results. How can I allow users to specify case insensitive searches to retrieve good results?

FYI: I'm using DynamoDB with Node.js and Express, with AngularJS on the front-end. The script for the scan request to the db sits in an Express route js file; the code to interpret the user request and send to the server is in an AngularJS controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up your DynamoDB table to AWS ElasticSearch with a Lambda function to stream updates in your table to be indexed. ElasticSearch allows full text and case-insensitive lookups so it is exactly what you are looking for. Here is an [example architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/indexing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda/) by AWS solution architects. AWS Labs also offers the [DynamoDB Logstash plugin](https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-input-dynamodb) that accomplishes the same task.