# AWS - dynamodb - How to do a search in similar text?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamodb, and I store in it a content similar to this:

```
Product Code | Title
1 | Computer
2 | Notebook
```

But when I use the SCAN function to fetch the records, it only finds if I put "Computer" (Exactly the same)

If I put "computer" do not think anything.

Json being sent to SCAN:

```
{
    "TableName": "products",
    "ScanFilter": { 
      "Title" : { 
         "AttributeValueList": [ 
            { 
               "S": "computer"
            }
         ],
         "ComparisonOperator": "CONTAINS"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284045/query-dynamodb-with-case-insensitive-condition) - it's not as easy as you might like.

Comment: For the case of the uppercase solved, but now I noticed another problem, no accent is found

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB doesn’t support fuzzy matching for either of its’ querying APIs. If you need fuzzy matching you will have to either use a different database technology or cone up with a combination of DynamoDB + something else.

ElasticSearch comes to mind as a great fulltext search engine that supports similarity searches very well.