# How to Scan multiple attributes in DynamoDB with java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have this scan expression which returns a list of blogs matching the query (By title). How can I scan multiple attributes in the table and also ignore the case of the query?

```
      public List<BlogDetailsEntity> searchBlogs(String query) {
    try {
      DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
      scanExpression.addFilterCondition("title", new Condition()
              .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.CONTAINS)
              .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(query)));
     scanExpression.addFilterCondition("shortDescription", new Condition()
              .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.CONTAINS)
              .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(query)));
      return dynamoDBMapper.scan(BlogDetailsEntity.class, scanExpression);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      log.error("failed to get blogs > " + query);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: If you need general purpose search, you should consider an actual search engine, such as Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

- Multiple attributes: you can have multiple [filter conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBScanExpression.html#addFilterCondition-java.lang.String-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Condition-) on a single scan.
- Ignore casing: As of 2017, this was [not available](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=92159). The suggested [work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284045/query-dynamodb-with-case-insensitive-condition) is to add a field to the objects with the value in lowercase and filter on that.

Comment: I added another filter condition but it only filters based on the first condition (See updated code)

Comment: Interesting. Can you show an example of your DynamoDB objects?